# XML to python, save variables for futher optimization

Tags: python, xml, optimization

I have an issue to extract and save in a list some variables from an XML file.
Here's a part of the XML file:

```
  '''  <CoverRequirements>
        <DayOfWeekCover>
          <Day>Monday</Day>
          <Cover>
            <Shift>E</Shift>
            <Preferred>2</Preferred>
          </Cover>
          <Cover>
            <Shift>L</Shift>
            <Preferred>2</Preferred>
          </Cover>
        </DayOfWeekCover>
        <DayOfWeekCover>
          <Day>Tuesday</Day>
          <Cover>
            <Shift>E</Shift>
            <Preferred>2</Preferred>
          </Cover>
          <Cover>
            <Shift>L</Shift>
            <Preferred>2</Preferred>
          </Cover>
        </DayOfWeekCover>
       </CoverRequirements>
      '''
```

Here's my code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xmlfile = 'sprint01.xml'

tree = ET.parse(xmlfile)
root = tree.getroot()

days_week_cover = []
shift_cover = []
preferred_cover = []

for cover_data in root.find('CoverRequirements'):
    
    #level 2
    days = cover_data.find('Day')
    days_week_cover.append(days.text)
    #level 3
    cover = cover_data.find('Cover')
    
    shift = cover.find('Shift')
    shift_cover.append(shift.text)
    
    preferred1 = cover.find('Preferred')
    preferred_cover.append(preferred1.text)
    
print(days_week_cover) #I get: ['Monday', 'Tuesday']
print(shift_cover) # I get ['E','E'] instead of ['E','L','E','L']
print(preferred_cover) # I get ['2','2'] instead of ['2','2','2','2']
```

For the variables shift_cover and preferred_cover instead of getting ['E','L','E','L'] and ['2','2','2','2'] I get ['E','E'], ['2','2']. It looks like it only save in the list the first element of the level 3, XML file.
I tried some variations by including a new for in function in the level 3 code in order to iterate in all elements of the level 3 but I get an error. Any help would be appreciated, thank you !
In term of time to solve the code, is this optimal ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably better off using lxml with xpath, for this type of thing:

```
from lxml import etree
cover = """[your xml above]"""
doc = etree.XML(cover)

days_week_cover = []
shift_cover = []
preferred_cover = []

for period in doc.xpath('//DayOfWeekCover'):
    days_week_cover.append(period.xpath('.//Day')[0].text)
    for shift in period.xpath('.//Shift'):
        shift_cover.append(shift.text)
    for pref in period.xpath('.//Preferred'):
        preferred_cover.append(pref.text)

print(days_week_cover)
print(shift_cover)
print(preferred_cover)
```

Output:

```
['Monday', 'Tuesday']
['E', 'L', 'E', 'L']
['2', '2', '2', '2']
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use the xml2dict library to have great control over your object.

for installing xml2dict you can use the following command

```
pip install xmltodict
```

And then you can use it in your code like this

```
import xmltodict, json

obj = xmltodict.parse("""
<employees>
    <employee>
        <name>Dave</name>
        <role>Sale Assistant</role>
        <age>34</age>
    </employee>
</employees>
""")

print(obj)
```

P.S: you can read your file as a string using the following snippet code

```
with open('data.xml', 'r') as file:
    data = file.read()
```